# Cannot link opencv-3.2.0 when cross compile for beaglebone black

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I created a rootfs directory for beaglebone black by chroot and install libopencv-dev for this target.
When I try cross compile with CMAKE_SYSROOT=<rootfs_dir> and link opencv lib to build the app it cannot work.

**the toolchain file:**

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING TRUE)
# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

# where is the target environment 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})
# search for programs in the build host directories

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

**the CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(SRC_FILES helloworld_opencv.cpp)
set(HEADER_FILES helloworld_opencv.hpp)

find_package(OpenCV 3.2.0 EXACT REQUIRED)
add_executable(HelloWorldOpenCV ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

target_include_directories(HelloWorldOpenCV PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(HelloWorldOpenCV PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})

install(
  FILES ${HEADER_FILES}
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include
)

install(
  TARGETS HelloWorldOpenCV
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin
)
install(
    FILES chart.png
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin
)
```

It found opencv lib in the target rootfs, but the problem here is when I use
target_link_libraries(HelloWorldOpenCV PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})
It always links some header file from host machine, and when I comment this line it links the header file from target rootfs as I expected

**The log when build:**

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- CMAKE SYSROOT: /home/vinhnt/bluesky/../rootfs
-- Found OpenCV: /home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr (found suitable exact version "3.2.0")
-- Found OpenCV
-- OPENCV LIB: opencv_calib3dopencv_coreopencv_features2dopencv_flannopencv_highguiopencv_imgcodecsopencv_imgprocopencv_mlopencv_objdetectopencv_photoopencv_shapeopencv_stitchingopencv_superresopencv_videoopencv_videoioopencv_videostabopencv_vizopencv_arucoopencv_bgsegmopencv_bioinspiredopencv_ccalibopencv_datasetsopencv_dpmopencv_faceopencv_freetypeopencv_fuzzyopencv_hdfopencv_line_descriptoropencv_optflowopencv_phase_unwrappingopencv_plotopencv_regopencv_rgbdopencv_saliencyopencv_stereoopencv_structured_lightopencv_surface_matchingopencv_textopencv_ximgprocopencv_xobjdetectopencv_xphoto
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vinhnt/bluesky/build
Scanning dependencies of target HelloWorldOpenCV
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/helloworld_opencv/CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpenCV.dir/helloworld_opencv.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:41:0,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:501,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from /home/vinhnt/bluesky/src/helloworld_opencv/helloworld_opencv.cpp:3:
/home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:43:9: error: ‘__int_least8_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__intptr_t’?
 typedef __int_least8_t int_least8_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         __intptr_t
/home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:44:9: error: ‘__int_least16_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__int16_t’?
 typedef __int_least16_t int_least16_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         __int16_t
/home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:45:9: error: ‘__int_least32_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__int32_t’?
 typedef __int_least32_t int_least32_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         __int32_t
/home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:46:9: error: ‘__int_least64_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__int64_t’?
 typedef __int_least64_t int_least64_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         __int64_t
/home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:49:9: error: ‘__uint_least8_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__uintmax_t’?
 typedef __uint_least8_t uint_least8_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         __uintmax_t
/home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:50:9: error: ‘__uint_least16_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__uint16_t’?
 typedef __uint_least16_t uint_least16_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         __uint16_t
/home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:51:9: error: ‘__uint_least32_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__uint32_t’?
 typedef __uint_least32_t uint_least32_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         __uint32_t
/home/vinhnt/rootfs/usr/include/stdint.h:52:9: error: ‘__uint_least64_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__uint64_t’?
 typedef __uint_least64_t uint_least64_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         __uint64_t
In file included from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:501:0,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from /home/vinhnt/bluesky/src/helloworld_opencv/helloworld_opencv.cpp:3:
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:58:11: error: ‘::int_least8_t’ has not been declared
   using ::int_least8_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:59:11: error: ‘::int_least16_t’ has not been declared
   using ::int_least16_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:60:11: error: ‘::int_least32_t’ has not been declared
   using ::int_least32_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:61:11: error: ‘::int_least64_t’ has not been declared
   using ::int_least64_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:76:11: error: ‘::uint_least8_t’ has not been declared
   using ::uint_least8_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:77:11: error: ‘::uint_least16_t’ has not been declared
   using ::uint_least16_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:78:11: error: ‘::uint_least32_t’ has not been declared
   using ::uint_least32_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7/cstdint:79:11: error: ‘::uint_least64_t’ has not been declared
   using ::uint_least64_t;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/helloworld_opencv/CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpenCV.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'src/helloworld_opencv/CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpenCV.dir/helloworld_opencv.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/helloworld_opencv/CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpenCV.dir/helloworld_opencv.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: recipe for target 'src/helloworld_opencv/CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpenCV.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/helloworld_opencv/CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpenCV.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

anyone got this problem, please help me!

Comment: These double-underscore names were introduced to glibc in 2018 and they should be defined in `/usr/include/<platform>/bits/types.h`. If your installation has a wrong version of `bits/types.h` for your platform, you could experience this error. Run `/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -H simpleprogram.cpp` where the program `#include`s `<cstdint>` and see where `bits/types.h` comes from.

Comment: Thank you, seem I found the mistake when I left the rootfs of target env is out of the project, now I moved it into the project the error that I described above is gone, but I still got some other errors and I still work with it :))